# Parsing XML files in R for NLP, but code returns empty

Tags: r, xml, nlp

I'm trying to preprocess large TEI-encoded XML files, in order to later use ggplot2 to visualize results. I am using code from Matt Jockers, which all seems to be working. But instead of returning data, I get a list of 6 NULL values (6 being the number of files). Why am I getting empty lists??

Code is here for reference, though files are limited-access

```
setwd("C:/Users/Amanda/Desktop/WWO/WWO")
input.dir <- "Wroth and Sidney Herbert/R corpus"

files.v <- dir(path=input.dir, pattern=".*xml")
file.path(input.dir, files.v)


getTEIWordTableList <- function(doc.object){
 paras <- getNodeSet(doc.object,
              "/tei:TEI/tei:text/tei:body//tei:p",
             c(tei = "http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"))
 words <- paste(sapply(paras,xmlValue), collapse=" ")
 words.lower <- tolower(words)
 words.l <- strsplit(words.lower, "\\W")
 word.v <- unlist(words.l)
 book.freqs.t <- table(word.v[which(word.v!="")])
book.freqs.rel.t <- 100*(book.freqs.t/sum(book.freqs.t))
return(book.freqs.rel.t)}

book.freqs.l <- list() 

for(i in 1:length(files.v)){
doc.object <- xmlTreeParse(file.path(input.dir, files.v[i]),
                    useInternalNodes=TRUE)
worddata <- getTEIWordTableList(doc.object)
book.freqs.l[[files.v[i]]] <- worddata}
```

Thanks in advance! I'm new to XML parsing.

EDIT: adding first chunk of XML text

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-model href="../schema/wwp-store.rng"    type="application/xml"schematypens="http://relaxng.org/ns/structure/1.0"?><?xml-model href="../schema/wwp-store.isosch" type="application/xml"schematypens="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron"?><!-- $Id: sidney.antonie.xml 29592 2016-09-16 13:49:08Zsyd $ --><TEI xmlns="http://www.wwp.northeastern.edu/ns/textbase"xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
<teiHeader xml:id="TR00204.hdr">
    <fileDesc>
      <titleStmt>
        <title type="main">The Tragedie of Antony, 1595</title>
        <author><persName ref="p:msidney.enw" type="person-female">Sidney, Mary, Countess of Pembroke</persName>, trans. (from <persName ref="p:rgarnier.pbo" type="person-male">Robert Garnier</persName>)</author>
    <sponsor>Brown University</sponsor>
    <sponsor>Northeastern University</sponsor>
    <funder>U.S. National Endowment for the Humanities</funder>
```

Comment: A snippet of the XML would be helpful to us to help you.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your code seems to search a specific XPath expression. Can you make sure that your TEI files have the structure TEI/body//p? This means that the root element is TEI followed by body and body has a descendant named p

Comment: Added XML above; Yannis P., I'll try to sort out my XPath.